# Spring Security redirect back to refer URL after login and logout

Tags: spring, grails, redirect, spring-security, grails-plugin

I am using Spring Security for authentication. The login and logout buttons are placed on the page layout, which is used by all pages. I have a BookController which needs a parameter for the create action (e.g., an image id):

```
class BookController {

@Secured("ROLE_USER")   
def create() {
  def someImage = params.imageId
  ...
}
@Secured("ROLE_USER")   
def show() {
  ...
}
...
}
```

My LoginController is:

```
class LoginController {
...
def auth() {
  ...
  redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
}
...
}
```

This will redirect the user to the base URL after login was successful. I want to have the user always be redirected to the refer URL, which is the URL before he was successfully logged in.

For example: 
The user is not logged in. He is at home/index and want to access book/create, which is only available for logged-in users. In this case, Spring Security will redirect the user to login/auth and (after he is successfully logged in) to / (which is the base URL).

I want to have the redirect go to the URL the user has been trying to access, which in this case is book/create. This should also be the case for any other action. If a not-logged-in user on home/index tries to access book/show/32333, he will be redirected to login/auth, and, after he successfully logs in, back to book/show/32333.

How can I implement that?

Comment: Mine does this OotB.  Do you have any custom SuccessHandlers?

Comment: No I do not have any custom SuccessHandlers. Any idea?

Comment: Show spring-security configuration.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample? I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the following solution:

```
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false)
        def referUrl
        def referParamsMap
        def referParams = "?"
        if(session != null) {
            SavedRequest savedRequest = new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response)
            if(savedRequest != null) {
                referUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl()
                referParamsMap = savedRequest.getParameterMap()
                referParamsMap.each { referParams += "${it.key}=${it.value[0]}&" }
            }
        }
        println "referUrl "+referUrl+referParams
        if(referUrl != null)
            redirect url: referUrl+referParams
        else
            redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
```

The only problem is, that if a not logged in user is on a page and loggs in (by clicking on a login link at the layout GSP) he will alway be redirected to the defaultTargetUrl not to the page he has been before.

Is there a way to get the correct url in this case?